# Is there a source that Dalai Lama wants scientists to invent a "meditation machine"?

Tags: reference-request, meditation, science, dalai-lama

The 14th Dalai Lama have known to actively support scientific explanation on Buddhism. For example his investment in the [Mind and Life Institute](https://www.mindandlife.org/). But I remember that I've read somewhere that he jokingly requests scientists to invent a meditation machine, because meditating 4 hours every morning is very hard, but I can't find it again. Is there a source of that?

Comment: This question is a repeat. I couldn't find a written record of such a comment, if a video exists it will be impossible to find the reference as it must be a passing comment not an entire discourse. I am sure he meant it as a joke. What is your actual requirement with the reference? If you can reframe the question with it, may be we can be able to help.

Comment: What do you mean by repeat? Yes I'm sure this meant as a joke, but I think this also meant that he appreciated scientific evidence of meditation. I want to have a short but strong example on his appreciation, and think that this is the best.

Comment: appreciation of 'scientific evidance of meditation' is also still vague to interpret....i found this page has lots of resources you can get your answers with....  https://liveanddare.com/benefits-of-meditation/

Comment: See also this topic about [meditating in the morning](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/problems-with-meditation-in-the-morning)

Comment: If you're looking for "scientific evidence of meditation" you might like [The Pursuit of Happiness](http://www.cbc.ca/news2/background/meditation/) about using a MRI to measure brain activity (of Tibetan monks)

Comment: @BodhiWalker We could close a new question as a duplicate, only if we can identify where the question has been previously asked, and confirm it's just the same question, *and* that previous question already has some answer[s] to the new question.

Comment: @ChrisW ok...i got some kind of time dilation...it felt like i read the exact question 2 days back...like an exact one...it was wired...so i flaged.

Comment: @BodhiWalker i just recently dumb edit the question to make it jump on the top

Comment: @Ooker yeah mate...thats why i said it was repeat...you got me all worried...I actually started thinking that they made some changes inside the Matrix...LOL...if u know what i meant.

Comment: There's also https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/zen-and-brain if you want to dive into research on this.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find is in a [NeuroScience conference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgtz4RuH7II&ab_channel=UniversityofCaliforniaTelevision%28UCTV%29) from 2012 where scientists and the Dalai Lama are discussing the similarities of human brain activity with that of animals and machines. That part of the conversation starts around minute 34. There is no explicit request from the Dalai Lama in there to create such a device.